# Keys enumeration, not returning ASCII equivalent for all punctuation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c++-cli, keycode

I have the following key handler:

```
void Form1::texBox_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender,
             System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e) {
    //New lines in response to suggestion of using keypress
    if (Control::ModifierKeys == Keys::Alt) return;
    e->SuppressKeyPress=true;
    unsigned char chr = (unsigned char)e->KeyCode;
    //char chr = (char)e->KeyCode; //Gives negative 'values'
    if (chr < ' ') return;
    //else do stuff
}
```

This handles numbers and letters appropriately, but when I press any punctuation the KeyCodes go completely mental. Using signed `char` I got -66 for '.' and 190 with `unsigned char`.

I assume this must be due to something I messed with with Windows, please would someone offer a better way to handle textual keyboard outside of a Forms' standard document containers?

Keypress sounds good, will it work to supress output though? Maybe even 'Alt' detection (just to route the handy alt-F4 combo really)? Please see the two lines I added at method's entry point. KeyPress is easier than getting my dllimport to work, just need to handle arrow keys and page up/down, perhaps I need both...

Comment: I think you want `Char.IsControl()` in place of comparisons to hard-coded values.

Comment: I want ASCII keycodes, A=65 (or something). Basically 0..127 are ASCII standards. Oh wait, I see, UNICODE is the new ASCII perhaps?

Comment: .NET is Unicode (as is Java).  Unicode is an internationalized standard that supports more than just unaccented Latin characters.

Comment: "Keycodes" is ambiguous in this context; the Windows developer documentation uses this term for the "codes" sent by the keyboard hardware, which includes non-character keys like F1, Home/End, Ins/Del etc.  So, since not all keys correspond to an ASCII (or Unicode) character, we need to differentiate between "keycodes" (hardware) and "character codes" (ASCII or Unicode).

Comment: It only "handles letters and numbers appropriately" if your keyboard layout is "US QWERTY".

Comment: Yes, I think you need both.  But the arrow keys and PgUp/PgDn are (presumably) going to reposition the cursor, not alter document  content, and vice versa ... so there should be little or no overlap (and since we're talking about different functionality you really want it in separate methods anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the `KeyDown` event is used mostly for handling "special" keys, i.e. function keys, Home/End, etc.  `KeyCode` is the actual keyboard (hardware) "scan code", which is not guaranteed to be the same as the Unicode character value.

If you want the character values, you probably want the `KeyPress` event instead of `KeyDown`.  However, if you also want to handle "special" keys, then you will need both.

Comment: Should that first "KeyPress" say "KeyDown"?

Answer (score 0):

Keycodes aren't ASCII.

You probably want to use the `KeyPress` event instead of `KeyDown`.  The event args for `KeyPress` include the `KeyChar` field which has an ASCII code (or Unicode, but for ASCII characters the Unicode value is the same).